# Loop through list to call different functions

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a list of integer, need to loop through the list and call different functions which all have the same input parameters, here is my code:

```
  def callRandomFunctions(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = {
    val randomList = Random.shuffle(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
    randomList.foreach { _ =>
      _ match {
        case 1 => func1(config, prefix)
        case 2 => func2(config, prefix)
        case 3 => func3(config, prefix)
        case 4 => func4(config, prefix)
      }
    }
  }

 def func1(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = {...}
 def func2(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = {...}
 def func3(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = {...}
 def func4(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = {...}
```

and got these errors:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function
[error] The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
[error] Expected type was: ?
[error]         _ match {
[error]         ^


[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
[error]     randomList.foreach {
[error]                        ^
[error] two errors found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply shuffle the functions and then call them directly.

```
def func1(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = ???
def func2(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = ???
def func3(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = ???
def func4(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = ???

def callRandomFunctions(config: config, prefix: String): Seq[ChainBuilder] =
  Random.shuffle(Seq(func1 _, func2 _, func3 _, func4 _))
        .map(_(config, prefix))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do this:

```
randomList.foreach {
    case 1 => func1(config, prefix)
    case 2 => func2(config, prefix)
    case 3 => func3(config, prefix)
    case 4 => func4(config, prefix)
}
```

and it will work as a pattern matching on number passed to `foreach` callback.

Another issue with your code is that you want to return `ChainBuilder` from `callRandomFunctions` but you're using `foreach` which is terminating operator returning `Unit`. You probably wanted to use `map` and change return type to `List[ChainBuilder]`:

```
def callRandomFunctions(config: Config, prefix: String): List[ChainBuilder] = {
    val randomList = Random.shuffle(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
    randomList.map {
        case 1 => func1(config, prefix)
        case 2 => func2(config, prefix)
        case 3 => func3(config, prefix)
        case 4 => func4(config, prefix)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for a more gatling-y solution

```
def callRandomFunctions(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = {
  val randomList = Random.shuffle(List(1, 2, 3, 4))

  exec(session => session.set("randomList")
  .forEach("${randomList}", "currentVal") {
    doSwitch("${currentVal}") (
       1 -> exec(func1(config: config, prefix: String)),
       2 -> exec(func2(config: config, prefix: String)),
       3 -> exec(func3(config: config, prefix: String)),
       4 -> exec(func4(config: config, prefix: String))
    )
  }
```

if the order of execution doesn't really need to be random you could also use a .roundRobinSwitch

Comment: does this execute all 4 functions (just in random order) or it randomly pick one function and execute it?

Comment: this solution executes all four in a random order

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the function by their name with reflection (although the performance isn't so great). 
You don't need the pattern matching and it's just another way of implementation:

You need to put all your function in a specific class:

```
case class FunctionsClass(config: config, prefix: String) {
  def func1(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = ???
  def func2(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = ???
  def func3(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = ???
  def func4(config: config, prefix: String): ChainBuilder = ???
}
```

Then, implement `callRandomFunctions` like this:

```
def callRandomFunctions(config: config, prefix: String):Unit = {
  val args = List(config, prefix)
  val argtypes = args.map(_.getClass)
  val functionsClassObj = FunctionsClass(config, prefix)
  val randomList = Random.shuffle(List(1, 2, 3, 4))

  val result = randomList.map{ i =>     
      val mtd = functionsClassObj.getClass.getMethod(s"func$i", argtypes: _*)
      Try {mtd.invoke(functionsClassObj, args: _*)}.recover { case _ => println("ERROR")}
  }

  result.filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get))
}
```

This way you are calling your `func` method based on the ids in your shuffled list